# Ajax return url of a name

Tags: arrays, json, ajax

```
JSON
links {
 name: "card";
 url: "http://google.com";
}



j.each(branch.links, function(i, supportlinks) {                                    
    console.log(supportlinks["card"].url);                                      
    });
```

How do I convert it into this below and output `url` with the link named `card`?

```
links {     
 card: "http://google.com";
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you iterating over?  What is `j`?  What is `branch.links`?  What is `supportlinks`?  Your JSON structure is just an object.  You'd simply reference the `url` property on that object.  Something like: `console.log(linksObj.url)`

Comment: @David, I updated the question. j is nonconflict $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = {};

j.each(branch.links, function(i, supportlinks) {                                    
    supportlinks[supportlinks.name] = supportlinks.url;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: there is multiple `name` with `url`. How can I do it so it is more global?

Comment: create a function or something so it always output the URL based on the parameter which is string

Comment: I really can't understand your needs, I suggest to edit your question and give more examples, like how your json looks like, and what result do you want